# Windows Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to connect to the remote server running Win Server 2008 Web using remote desktop? Or is this feature disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [Edition Comparison by Technical Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx), it can have 2 Remote Desktop Admin connections. So your answer is yes, it's possible.